# Email sent by a designer workflow does not display lookup information

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a simple list with a person's name (as a single  line of text not a people/groups) and a date. I have created a workflow that pauses until the date and then sends an email to one of my AD groups. The email includes a string lookup that returns the person's name column.

The email works fine except on Mondays when it does not display the person's name. The line is simply blank. Any thoughts?

I have tried creating a new list and workflow and still have the same problem. The server is not running any backups or anything at the time so I do not think it is interfering and the workflow report claims it ran successfully.

Comment: Do you use a calculated date in your field or just simply Date\Time field?

Comment: The field is just a Date/Time. I then use the step "set time portion of date/time field" in the workflow